# How to handle "no scene" in a scene transition attempt?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

In a button that's supposed to load a scene, I'm trying to learn to use a a `guard` statement, but pretty baffled by what it does in each of its four "escapes". And don't know what I'm supposed to do with regards handling the situation where there's no scene.

**Which is the correct to use here:** `continue`, `return`, `break` or `throw`?

And... why?

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if self.rr.contains(location) {
            guard let nextScene = goesTo
                else {print(" No such Scene ")
                continue } // continue, return, break, throw !!!!????
            loadScene(withIdentifier: nextScene)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use if let instead of guard let in ur situation! under the else u can easily continue it. I don't think that it's suitable to use guard let in that position!

Comment: Because: 1 I want to learn how to use a guard statement in a flow I already understand. 2. I want something drastic to happen if that scene isn't found, and I think that's the right place for guards... to guard against disaster... @Fay007

Comment: the guard statement structure usually comes with return, it means if the nextScene doesn't exist, return and do nothing but if it does, now you can use the nextScene value (which is not possible in if let). you cannot use "continue" or "break" because they are only allowed inside a loop or switch statements.

Comment: @Mina so a return statement goes back to the `if self.rr.contains...` scope?

Comment: @Confused, yes, the return only return the guard statement. the pointer will be at 'loadScene(withIdentifier: nextScene)' .
this link is helpful -> http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/

Comment: So a `return` will effectively nullify the purpose of using the `guard`, in this case, right?

Comment: @Confused no. Return IS the purpose of guard in this case. See my answer inc...

Comment: See my other question, in the comment to the other answer. In this situation, is there any flow difference between a `continue` and a `return`? @Fluidity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a for loop then `continue` will move to the next iteration, while `break` will exit the for loop. `Return` will always exit the current function.

In this case you would want to put the guard statement before the for loop and exit touchesEnded, since I presume `goesTo` is set elsewhere.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let nextScene = goesTo else {
        print(" No such Scene ")
        return // exit touchesEnded since goesTo is not defined 
    }

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if self.rr.contains(location) {
            loadScene(withIdentifier: nextScene)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If only considering my example, in the original question, and this code being in a button, and there being only one touch on the button, by one finger... is it true that `return`, `continue` and `break` will provide the same result?

Comment: Thank you for the context and explanation! Too! Very succinct, very well written, very clear. You should consider writing documentation, you have a rare talent!!! As a result of the insight and understanding conveyed by your wonderful articulation, I've discovered a fundamental folly in my approach. There are four buttons on the screen, each goes to a different scene, each has this code, and `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`. However dragging out of one button and into another doesn't activate the button dragged into. Only the first button touched can be re-entered, no new entries acknowledged

Comment: @Confused in your situation you would get basically the same result from `return`, `continue` and `break` but best to understand the intention of each statement and know that exiting a for loop is not the same as exiting a function e.g. if you use `break` and exit the for loop, then later add code after the for loop, this new code will execute unintentionally. So best to always apply the command that describes your intention.

Comment: @Confused is there a reason to allow dragging to select buttons? A `UITapGestureRecognizer` would lock down the button behaviour to a single tap.

Comment: I'm exploring many things of how SpriteKit and iOS and Swift work, all at the same time, from a (heavily) designer focused perspective... which means attempting to understand what can and can't be done, how, why... etc. From a designer's point of view, the ability to cancel and change decisions (at any time) is the ideal usability. So I'd like, on this screen of four buttons (to cater for those that do as they think) to be able to change their minds, midstream. Meaning they be able to go from one button to another without loading a scene, via drag. Hence using `touchesEnded` to load.

Comment: btw thank you for clarifying the result of the use of `return`, `continue` and `break`. I was sure this was the case, in this situation, but couldn't figure out how to confirm it. I knew I was abusing/miss-using `guard`, in this scenario, but wanted to see how it worked in terms of a scope I already understand before exploring it in newer environments and uses I'm not yet familiar with. Exhaustive, microcosmic focus on anal details, I know... but important to how I grasp a whole of something's abilities. My apologies for the trivial nature of the question and it being hypothetical in nature.

Comment: I think `throw` is what I actually want, here, since I desperately need to know if there's no scene available with the right name. But I have yet to learn how to use `throw`, since it needs arbitrarily created destinations, so far as I can tell from the docs and Swift book.

Comment: @Confused `throw` is not commonly used in iOS and will crash your App if not handled properly! This [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/130197/magical-error-handling-swift) is quite an entertaining look at error handling in Swift.

Comment: And to think I had nearly completely written off Ray's House of Horrors as an ad platform for consulting programmers...

Comment: yes, I know... knew, you'd be out of shape about this... but look at how eloquently and succinctly this guy is getting to the point! He must be Australian ;) @Fluidity

Comment: And.. he's using the example given in the question... which I can't emphasize enough, was/is the point and basis for the context and reasoning of the question, and the need/desire for the answer... @Fluidity. Which is not to say I don't appreciate your efforts, I do! Greatly. You got me from nowhere of confusion to bewildered and optimistic.

Comment: @Confused i was "taking your piss" or something weird expression like that that nobody uses x} It is a good answer. I wasn't sure you knew how to use continue or break so I was giving examples with guard. I can never understand you the first time.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the scenery is suitable for guard statement as you have many cases under loop and you want to avoid some of the cases! First we need to know when should I use a guard statement. Yes, it helps you to handle error but that does not mean you should use it anywhere and everywhere!

> Why guard and when to use them and not to use them:
>
> [The Guard Statement in Swift](http://www.codingexplorer.com/the-guard-statement-in-swift-2/)

**update**

I hope this would clarify your problem

> when you are using break

```
let array: [Int?] = [3, 7, nil, 12, 40]

for arrayValue in array {

    guard let value = arrayValue else {
        print("No Value")
        break
    }

    print(value)
}
```

**output**

3

7

No Value

> when you are using continue

```
let array: [Int?] = [3, 7, nil, 12, 40]

for arrayValue in array {

    guard let value = arrayValue else {
        print("No Value")
        continue
    }

    print(value)
```

**output**

3

7

No Value

12

40

Return would close the function and would act same as the break in this case. Now please make decision according to your need! If you think it's ok to break it when there is no scene condition then break or if you want to skip it then just skip that exact scenario with continue. I hope you got my point

Comment: is it true that a return statement would have the same effect as a continue?

Comment: A return is to escape a running function/method... A continue will forcefully increment a step of the loop... So they are not same @Confused

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, all three would do essentially the same thing. But it's weird to use a loop in `touchesEnded` because It's the last touch, and there is only one touch, unless you have multigesture going on.

If you were to add other code underneath your `for` loop, then you could perhaps break your program because you didn't handle the `guard` statement. Using `return` would be ideal if you want to just ignore the rest of the function on not having a scene.

```
// Break works with named labels, which can be used with while, do, and for.
// Why? Break exits loops because it's a command that redirects the
// execution of code, similar to goto in C.

outerLabel: do {
    if 0==0 { print("numbers are fun and,") }
    if 0==2 { break outerLabel } // NOTE: the label is required for
                                 // `break` when not in `while` or `switch`
    print("zero was not equal to two")
}

// Continue breaks from the current iteration (whatever value `i` is at),
// but then restarts the loop with the next value (0..1..2..3...)
for i in 1...10 {
  print(" Hello ")
  if 0==0 { continue }
  print(" Worlllddd ") // We will see 10 hellos but no worlds.
}


// Here is the example with guard
stuff: do {
  guard 0 == 2 else { break stuff } // Again, the label here is required for break.
  print(" zero is equal to two " ) // Doesn't print, lol...
}

moreStuff: for i in 1...10 {
  print(" is zero equal to two? ")
  guard 0 == 0 else { continue } // Label is optional for continue.
  print(" zero is equal to zero " ) // Does print.
}

// Here is how we use return with guard, and the print maybe explains why:
func ohLookAFunc() {
  guard 0 == 0 else {
    print(" Math and numbers as we know it are over!! ")
    return
    // ... now we xit from this crazy Func where 0 is not 0
    // You can handle this exception in any-way you see fit.
    // So if your scene doesn't exist, or if 0 is == 2, then 
    // it's up to you to figure out what to do in such disastrous
    // situations ;)
  }
  print(" Now we continue the function safe in the fact that 0 is still equal to 0")
}
```

There is no "best" use of these statements. It just depends on what *you* are doing and what logic *you* have set up.

Nobody can tell you what to do if the scene isn't found, other than to just ignore the input (return from `touchesEnded()` without doing anything).

Or, you could set it up so that way there is certainty that there will always be a correct scene to display. That part is on you :) and without more code, we can't help you with ensuring that.

Comment: what does break do without labels? It's often used without labels in the `while` statements. I hate to keep harping on the same question, but it really is as simple as this to help me see: what's different, in flow, between `continue` and `break` in the example I've given in my question?

Comment: there is always something to `continue` to, it just rolls on. In my question, what does `break` do that is different from `continue`?

Comment: What does break do, in my example, that's different from continue??????????????????????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130047/discussion-between-fluidity-and-confused).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about this crash from `continue`? I'm reasonably sure it will exist this scope, and continue to the next outer scope. But I don't know, and I don't know how to check.